# A diagonal Chern curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\to X$ be a rank $r$ holomorphic Hermitian vector bundle over a (compact) Kahler manifold.

Are there conditions on $E$ and/or the metric $h$ such that there exists everywhere a local frame in which the curvature $F_h$ of $h$ is a diagonal matrix of (pure imaginary) 2-forms?
$$F_h=\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_1 & & \\
& \ddots & \\
& & \omega_r
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: An obvious necessary condition is that the curvature form $F_h$ at every point should take values in an abelian subalgebra of ${\frak{u}}(r)$.  If one assumes, in addition, that its values at each point actually fill out a *maximal* abelian subalgebra of ${\frak{u}}(r)$, then one can clearly smoothly conjugate $F_h$ to make it diagonal, which then provides a smooth frame field of the desired kind.